# not getting the right value onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a slider and two buttons for left and right 
I have tow event handlers for each button as I'll show you in the code bellow.

when I click and wait for the transition to be completed, everthing works fine,
but when I click fast consecutive clicks ,I'm getting float not exact numbers as expected (as shown in the HTML bellow)

***this is Javascript and Jquery mixed together :***

```
var left = document.getElementById("left");
var right = document.getElementById("right");
var container = document.getElementById("container");


    left.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var marginLeft = container.style.marginLeft;
        var parsedMarginLeft = parseInt(marginLeft);
        console.log(parsedMarginLeft);
        if(parsedMarginLeft > -800) {
            $('#container').animate({marginLeft: '-=200px'}, 0);
        }
    });



    right.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var marginLeft = container.style.marginLeft;
        var parsedMarginLeft = parseInt(marginLeft);
        console.log(parsedMarginLeft);

        if(parsedMarginLeft < 0) {
            $('#container').animate({marginLeft: '+=200px'}, 0);
        }
    });
```

***And this is the html I get after the clicks :***

```
<div id="container" style="width: 1800px; margin-left: -127.879px;">

</div>
```

Comment: At click time, `container.style.marginLeft` is non-integer. Therefore, `+=` an integer gives a non-integer

Comment: You could disable the buttons while the animation is going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the [:animated](https://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) selector as first line in your event listeners to test if the container div is running animation:

```js
var left = document.getElementById("left");
var right = document.getElementById("right");
var container = document.getElementById("container");


left.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if ($('#container:animated').length == 0) {
    var marginLeft = container.style.marginLeft;
    var parsedMarginLeft = parseInt(marginLeft);
    console.log(parsedMarginLeft);
    if(parsedMarginLeft > -800) {
      $('#container').stop().animate({marginLeft: '-=200px'}, 0);
    }
  }
});



right.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if ($('#container:animated').length == 0) {
    var marginLeft = container.style.marginLeft;
    var parsedMarginLeft = parseInt(marginLeft);
    console.log(parsedMarginLeft);

    if (parsedMarginLeft < 0) {
      $('#container').animate({marginLeft: '+=200px'}, 0);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="left">left</button>
<button id="right">right</button>
<div id="container" style="width: 1800px; margin-left: 0px;background-color: red;">
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much !
that worked !!
Much appreciated ;)